# Spring Boot CSRF with session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

In my app I'm using Spring Session (with redis). Now I need to add CSRF prevention.

I have to handle the frontend app + clients over REST.

If my understanding is correct, without the use of spring security etc. on login I need to create a token, store it in redis with session id association and return it to the client (as header for example).

And then on every request I need to check the token passed as the header if it's correct to prevent CSRF?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. What you are describing is called the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern). It is the most comprehensive way to protect against CSRF attacks. I would suggest you consider using Spring Security for CSRF protection, even if you are not using it for authentication. If not, you can still learn more about CSRF protection from the Spring Security [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#csrf).